# Magento not sending order email automatically after checkout

Tags: magento, email, checkout

Recently we've updated from Magento 1.6 to Magento 1.8. Since we're running Magento 1.8, Magento will no longer automatically send emails regarding orders. If we force this through Sales => Orders and then the "Send email"-button it's working fine.

All other email functions such as new account, lost password etc are working fine as well.

I've found lots of people with the same error I am experiencing, but have not found a working solution yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to configure your sales emails in System => Configuration => Sales Emails